# Remove a particular div of specific text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code in a php page

```
<div class="vmenu">

  <div class="first_li"><span >Add Shift</span></div>
 <div class="first_li"><span>Add Comment</span></div>

 </div>
```

Now I want to remove the div contains text "Add Shift" on document ready

Comment: Do you want to remove it with PHP from a string or you want to remove it with JS from DOM?

Comment: you need to accept answers at least for your previous questions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function(){

    $('.first_li span:contains('Add Shift')').remove();
});
```

Comment: $('.first_li span:contains('Add Shift')').remove(); is working fine but how to add again it. Actually I am doing this on condition basis. so I want to add it again in else condition

Comment: like this:

$('div.vmenu div:first-child').hide();

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) and [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/). Note that it's *case sensitive*

```
$('div:contains("Add Shift")').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div.vmenu div:first-child').remove();
```

check it out on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7CFAq/